# Is there an index on the primary key of a table?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, primary-key, indexing

Does having a primary key column mean there is an index on that column? If so, what kind of index is it?

Comment: Please check on this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462477/sql-primary-key-and-index

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server, which I believe from previous questions is what you're using, when you define a PRIMARY KEY, it will automatically have a index on that column which will default to being a CLUSTERED index. You can define whether it should be a NONCLUSTERED or a CLUSTERED index when you create the constraint.

Comment: +1 and FYI for the OP: Indexes are not covered by ANSI, though MySQL and SQL Server use the same terminology.  Oracle does not distinguish - they are just indexes.  Also re: SQL Server - a clustered index is created by default when defining a primary key, but the clustered index can be changed to associate other column(s) in the table.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a primary key implies an index.

If the primary key is clustered, the index will be part of the main table file.  It it's not clustered, it will be part of a separate index file.

Comment: So if I have a primary key(which necessarily I have) I can't have another clustered index? Because just one clustered index is possible. How can I say that I don't want it to be unclustered?

Comment: You can create a nonclustered primary key using the `nonclustered` keyword, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255(SQL.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

*It depends on the database.*

Some databases either require or automatically create primary key indexes as a way to enforce the uniqueness of a primary key. Others are perfectly happy to perform a full scan of the table.

Which database are you using?

EDIT:

- SQLServer (versions 7 - 2008) creates indexes or primary keys - you can control whether or not it is clustered.
- Older versions of Oracle (8i,9i) also create indexes when you add a unique key constraint. Newer versions (10g) don't seem to, based on the test case I just looked at.

Answer (score 1):

In any "real" database, yes having a primary key means having a unique index. In some databases, the primary key index can/will cluster on key values too.

Answer (score 1):

In all the DBs I've used, PRIMARY KEY is basically just a UNIQUE index.

Comment: I think this is basically correct.  So +1 to compensate for the unexplained downvote :)