# Should all database tables have a primary key?

Tags: database, primary-key

Is it good practice to give every database table a primary key?  It seems to me that if the primary key is not explicitly needed, then it would just be extra clutter in my database.

Comment: OLTP: Yes, almost always. Datamart/Warehouse/Denormalised Reporting Tables: Depends, often not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a database table always have primary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831850/should-a-database-table-always-have-primary-keys)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### When you probably WOULD:

In an OLTP database you'd almost always (in my case always) have a primary key of some sort.  Sometimes Guid, sometimes autonumber/identity fields, sometimes set by the application or the customer.  Sometimes even a combination of more than one field.  This is because you'll typically want to uniquely identify any given row from the table.

Also, a primary key is a constraint used by the query optimiser that should improve performance for lookups and joins.

### When you probably WOULDN'T:

The only time you wouldn't have a primary key is in a "reporting" table, probably in a denormalised data warehouse.

Comment: How about relational tables? GameGenre, SellerItems?

Comment: On the assumption that those are the many-to-many tables joining two other tables together, then you could either have a surrogate key, or more likely, treat the combination of "parent" ID values as the PK.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is good practise to have a primary key on every table.

But, NOT every table should have a single auto number id column. I felt the need to spell that out, because for some reason lots of people tend to throw in an extra ID in all tables even though a perfectly good candidate already exist. For example, a many-to-many table representing `Users <-> Groups` should use `{user_id, group_id}`.

Apart from stopping duplicates at the door, a primary key constraint also carries information which is used by the optimizer when generating execution plans.

This is why I always, or at least with very few exceptions, have a primary key on all tables I create.
In fact, I even create primary keys on reporting tables where most of the columns are part of the primary key. Because during development, I will get at least one unique constraint violation because I did something wrong. With shitloads of data and no constraint in place I wouldn't have spotted the error.

Answer (score 4):

It's not required, but be sure that you don't ever need one.  The purpose of the primary key is so that you can [uniquely identify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) one row from another based on a (usually minimal) set of criteria.  This allows the database to ensure that you don't have duplicate data, for example, which also allows your database to conform to [1st normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).  If this isn't required then you don't need a primary key, but think carefully about it first.

Don't forget that the primary key doesn't necessarily have to be an additional column that contains an arbitrary unique value - it can also be a set of columns which together define uniqueness (e.g., a person's first name, last name and date of birth in an address book table).

Comment: "but you be sure that you don't ever need one" -- what do you mean by this? britishmutt don't speak proper English like what I does! :)

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of keys in relational database design is to prevent duplicate data and thereby help ensure data integrity. If you permit duplicate rows then you create ambiguity, potential update anomalies and very possibly incorrect results. Therefore in general every table ought to have at least one key (and maybe more than one if required). It's not usually the case that data integrity is "not explicitly needed"!

A primary key is just any one of the keys of a table. Designating one key as a primary key can be useful but is not particularly important - the important thing is that each table have at least one candidate key.

The reasons why duplicate rows ought to be avoided are covered pretty extensively in  database literature. See:

http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/627052.htm

http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/638922.htm

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=77708

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Issues-Database-Management-Practitioner/dp/0201485559](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485559)

Comment: Not **all** tables need primary keys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621450/should-all-database-tables-have-a-primary-key/4621497#comment14385367_4621497

Answer (score 2):

Generally yes - I'd make exceptions for tables that are simply rolled up versions of 'real' data stored for reporting purposes (i.e. rollup tables created for reporting/performance reasons), but generally I always have a primary key - and in my apps, its almost always an auto-increment integer that takes almost no extra space relative to the row size.

Answer (score 1):

While primary keys are hugely useful (and I use them all the time), let's be clear that there's no need to create a primary key if you don't need one.  There are cases where you don't need one, among them:

- a table that just collects data (for persistence purposes) to be queried itself and not related to other tables where the other tables needed to find the precise row being related to
- you don't need to enforce any kind of uniqueness in your table

In both cases above, you may be interested purely in aggregate info about a table and not in identifying a row uniquely.  I believe there are others.  But not using primary keys are fine -- this is why they are not required when you create a table (in most systems).

Comment: Why would you want to duplicate data in a table? The fact that you want to query a table implies that you want to know what each row represents. If you don't have a key then you don't know that - e.g. it could be one row per (x), (y) or (x,y,z) and effective use of the data becomes nearly impossible.

Comment: Not true, you may just purely be interested in aggregate information (sums, counts, etc).  Ask yourself why primary key constraints are not required by DB systems.  I am not saying primary keys are not hugely useful - I use them all the time, but that wasn't the question here.  Try to open your mind for a minute and consider that you may simply want to store data where you want to analyze it in aggregate, without relating it to other data in your database system (though you may want to relate the aggregate results).

Comment: I have edited my original response -- I think I came across as too liberal (my mistake).  I definitely do believe in and use primary keys regularly (because they make sense).  My main point is that there are use cases where you don't technically need them, which I thought was the spirit of the question.

Comment: Aggregation is no good reason not to have a key. The key is used to ensure that data cannot become erroneously duplicated. There is no logical reason for stating the same fact twice so there is no particular advantage to having duplicate data in a database system. The disadvantages on the other hand are well known. The reason SQL DBMSs permit tables and queries with duplicates is that they are not true RDBMSs. This is the biggest flaw of SQL and greatly complicates the language and its implementations. A few minutes Googling "duplicate rows" will confirm just what a major problem this is.

Comment: Suppose there's no natural key on the data (I hope you don't disagree this is possible).  Now suppose you use a surrogate key (e.g., an ID column).  And you never relate that table to another table.  You're telling me that surrogate key is useful?

Comment: That's exactly the point I raised in my first comment: Why would you want to design a table without a natural key (i.e. a key that identifies facts in the universe of discourse)? Duplicating information in a database table is fundamentally not a useful or accurate way to model the real world and generally indicates incomplete analysis or flawed design. You might be forced to do it if DBMS limitations don't permit you to implement the required keys but the question is about *good practice* and good practice in relational database design means tables with keys.

Comment: You never *want* to design a table w/o a primary key, but you may not have a choice.  Suppose you're storing tweets from Twitter.  There's no natural key there - the same user can make the same tweet at the same time (spam happens all the time like that).  Yet you want to store the Twitter data for spam analysis.  You don't need to put a primary key on that table.  And actually the question was not necessarily about practice -- the question said "should ALL tables have primary keys".

Comment: Of course you have a choice if you design the table. If you want to represent duplicate tweets then no doubt you need to replicate them on multiple servers and analyse them. You'd better make sure you have a key that identifies one message from another even if they contain the same text. I'd be amazed if Twitter store such data without keys - but whether they do or not that's no excuse for anyone else not using keys.

Comment: @sqlvogel It depends on your use case. **Not all tables need primary keys.** There are definitely times when it is appropriate to store just *data*, and not *normalized data*.

Comment: @sqlvogel For example, I'm tracking the updates (changes) to a field. I do that using a table called *ChangeTracker*. It has only two columns, one called "Timestamp" which tracks the timestamp of the update (not unique because it is possible for the field to be updated more than once per timestamp), and the other called "Data" which holds the updated value. This table is useful because I want to do queries like "show the last X number of changes". Now can you explain why do I need a primary key for this table?

Comment: @Pacerier, Well you *cannot* answer the query you have suggested without a key because if there are duplicate timestamps then the table doesn't record in what order the changes happened. Tables have no inherent order so the *only* way to store a well-defined sequence in a table is to use a key. Why wouldn't you just make (Timestamp, Data) the key? All relational operations assume that tables don't have duplicate rows and many DBMSs actually disable some features for keyless tables. Those are a few good good reasons.

Comment: @sqlvogel We can. The query is `select*from table order by Timestamp desc limit X`. Yes, there exists duplicate timestamps. Yes, the table doesn't record the order for the rows with duplicate timestamps. But **look at the use case. I want the last X number of changes.** Even when there are duplicate timestamps, the query still answered the business-question. Even when **all** rows have equal timestamps, the query will return X *random* rows, but those X *random* rows are still considered the latest, since all rows have the same timestamp.

Comment: @Pacerier, If "random" is acceptable instead of "latest" then you might just as well make (Timestamp, Data) the key, add a count of the number of updates and then add a random number input to the query to get a random result if and when you find a random result is useful to you. I would prefer to work with queries that have well-defined results so that I can easily verify when the result is correct and when it isn't. I'm not clear what you think the advantage of not having a key is when you can get an equivalent but predictable result with one.

Comment: @sqlvogel You are misunderstanding me. What I want is not "random" results, but the latest X results. Assuming X = 5, what I want is the latest 5 results. In other words, the returned rows are **ordered by Timestamp col**. So what happens when Timestamp of the latest 5th row equals Timestamp of the latest 6th row? Then in this case, either the 5th or 6th row will be returned, since they **both tied as the 5th latest row**. The returned rows are **well-defined** and can be **easily verified** (check that the Timestamp for the returned rows >= the Timestamp for the unreturned rows). The....

Comment: ....advantages of not having a key is **obvious**. Maintenance of a primary key requires building a bayer tree to keep track of indexes. **This is not free** as it requires both space and time. Why create a primary key when it is not used?

Comment: You were the one who used the word "random" first, not me. It is of course a non-deterministic result rather than a "random" one. But non-deterministic results are often a problem because users and testers quite reasonably classify non-repeatable results as a bug. If you have a key you can get the same result *deterministically*, which is more useful for the vast majority of queries (hardly anyone  creates a table just to answer one single type of query). Indexes have nothing to do with it. Keys and indexes are different things and one does not necessarily imply the other.

Comment: The reasons why duplicate rows ought to be avoided are covered pretty extensively in database literature. I've added some references to my original answer to this question.

Comment: @sqlvogel I said that the rows returned would be *random* **only when** they share the same Timestamp. Non deterministic results are often **not a problem** because users and testers quite reasonably classify non-repeatable results as *part of the software product*. Are you aware that the display order for posts on this page is non-deterministic? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132260/159916. It is a **feature**, and **not a bug**. We don't need deterministic results **all** the time. Allow me to repeat my very first statement: It depends on the use case. **Not all tables need primary keys.**

Comment: Assuming we are using the same jargon, a primary key is an index: http://stackoverflow.com/a/462612/632951, http://bit.ly/KoBSkZ, http://bit.ly/LlxDEu, [the term key is sometimes used interchangeably with the term index](http://bit.ly/Kv1Wft). A primary key of a table ensures that all rows have unique values for the selected set of columns. Allow me to repeat my point above: **A primary key is not free.** Why create a primary key when it is not used? (please answer)

Comment: The reasons why data should be normalized is covered extensively in database literature. The reasons why data should **not** be normalized is equally covered in database literature. Simply, **ACID does not scale**: http://bit.ly/LmLDwb, http://bit.ly/LBJ2l9, http://bit.ly/K3neuv, http://bit.ly/L9gyk1, http://bit.ly/LV5Iu8, http://bit.ly/LmOHZ2, http://bit.ly/M4VuW7.

Comment: The techtarget.com link you posted actually explains that a key is a different thing from an index. Indexes are not the topic of this discussion. Of course non-deterministic results can be useful, but a key gives the user a *choice* of a deterministic result or not as the case may be. A key *could* and *would* be "used" for the case you described. You apparently want to impose duplicate data for reasons that aren't very clear. Allowing duplicates adds no expressive power to the system it just makes life more complex and less certain for consumers of that data.

Comment: I'm ignoring the comments on normalization and ACID. ACID properties have nothing much to do with whether a table has a key or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12533/discussion-between-pacerier-and-sqlvogel)

Answer (score 0):

I have a table that is partitioned by CreateDate which is not unique.  In my case I have decided to remove the primary key from this table because the fact that a primary key index must be unique meant that I couldn't make this index a LOCAL index, instead it has to be GLOBAL.  This would have meant that any deletion from that table (amongst other actions) would have made this primary key index unusable, rendering it useless.