# SQL Server 2008 timeout expired error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a simple sql call like :-

```
select col1,col2 from table1
```

and sometimes the system runs the following:-

```
update table1 
set col3 = 'something' 
where col1 ='s1' and col2 ='s2'
```

These queries are ran through various applications running on our server and it only happens on one table which has something like 100k rows.

I have tables with millions of rows - it doesn't timeout on them but not sure why it does on this one.

These queries run all day long without any problems but sometimes during the day - specially during peak times - they fail with error - timeout expired -

Can you please tell me what things can I try to resolve this error

Do I need to perform some type of locking ?

Also is it true that if a user is updating a comment and then other user on the system tries to update the same row in the table - will it timeout the 2nd user because the row is locked for editing - is there a way around that?

Comment: Do you have an index on col1 & col2?

Comment: What do you mean by an index? - do you mean if it is a primary key?

Comment: Yes - like a Primary Key - you may need a composite index (an index on more than one column) on col1 and col2 which could help with your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: i have already got that on col1 and col2 - they both together act as a primary key - the problem is not to do with that

Comment: ok - does either query run in a transaction? If so then perhaps a [table hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) may help (NOLOCK) - note that for `UPDATE`'s this is deprecated in SQL 2012.

Comment: @MichaelCapobianco A primary key automatically creates a clustered index. [You do not need an additional index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462477/sql-primary-key-and-index). Is there an index on col3? It could be that updating the index is taking a long time?

Comment: Could your timeout be too short on accident?

Comment: @MichaelCapobianco Timeout is 30 seconds - on a normal run it returns in 1 second max but sometimes no result. I have checked the desin of the table there is actually no indexing at all - the unique identity is maintained by the coding side i.e. and i have checked the table there are no duplicates too

Comment: Then you probably need to make col1 and col2 a primary key if they are supposed to be unique. This will create the index that should speed up your query. Or just add a nonclustered index to both columns.

Comment: @GarethD Also is it true that if a user is updating a comment and then other user on the system tries to update the same row in the table - will it timeout the 2nd user because the row is locked for editing - is there a way around that?

Comment: I think `ROWLOCK` will help, this will mean that 2 updates do not interfer with each other, but will negatively affect any `SELECT` statements that are using the table. Unfortunately it is unavoidable for 2 updates on the same row to compete with each other, but if the index works as expected the amount of time the query will run for should be so small concurrent updates will be a thing of the past!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer - 
Because it was a table in the old system - the previous users didn't add a primary key thinking that there is already a virtual primary key in there but it wasn't right.

As the sql would take too long for editing and would timeout.

So I just made a composite key in the table and now it is working alright.

Conclusion - Never have a table without a primary key if you are going to be dealing with updating,deleting data

Thanks everyone for your comments

Comment: *Conclusion - Never have a table without a primary key* Never give unconditional advice.