# Necessary to create index on multi field primary key in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, primary-key

Given the database table:

```
UserID (PK)
SomeTypeID (PK)
SomeSubTypeID (PK)
Data
```

And you wish to query:

```
SELECT Data FROM Table WHERE UserID = {0} AND SomeTypeID = {1} AND SomeSubTypeID = {2}
```

Would you need to create the index `UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubTypeID` or does the fact they form the primary key mean this is not needed?

Comment: The primary key already create an index of sorts. Unless you want to query the other columns isolated from each other it should be fine to only use the primary key. More detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039.aspx (assuming you use Microsoft SQL)

Comment: Possible duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462477/sql-primary-key-and-index?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created your primary key as:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType, Data 
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType))
```

Then the default index that is being created is a `CLUSTERED` index.

**Usually** (*so not all times*), when looking for data, you would want your queries to use a `NON-CLUSTERED` index to filter rows, where the columns you use to filter rows will form the key of the index and the information (column) that you return from those rows as an `INCLUDED` column, in this case `DATA`, like below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncl_indx 
ON TBL (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType) INCLUDE (Data);
```

By doing this, you're avoiding accessing the table data, through the `CLUSTERED` index.

**But**, you can specify the type of index that you want your `PRIMARY KEY` to be, so:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType, Data 
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType));
```

**Buuut**, because you want this to be defined as a `PRIMARY KEY` then you are not able to use the `INCLUDE` functionality, so you can't avoid the disk lookup in order to get the information from the `DATA` column, which is where you basically are with having the default `CLUSTERED` index.

**Buuuuuut**, there's still a way to ensure the uniqueness that the Primary Key gives you and benefit from the `INCLUDE` functionality, so as to do as fewer disk I/O's.

You can specify your `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` as `UNIQUE` which will ensure that all of your 3 columns that make up the index key are unique.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ncl_indx 
ON TBL (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType) INCLUDE (Data);
```

By doing all of these then your table is going to be a `HEAP`, [which is not a very good thing](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/). If you've given it a good thought in designing your tables and decided that the best clustering key for your `CLUSTERED INDEX` is (UserID, SomeTypeID, SomeSubType), then it's best to leave everything as you currently have it.

Otherwise, if you have decided on a different clustering key then you can add this unique nonclustered index, if you're going to query the table as you said you will.

Answer (score 1):

AS long as you use all the columns used in your primary key when filtering you don't need to create seperate indexes. Your primary key is ok in your example.

Think of creating seperate index if you plan to filter on one of the columns and not the others. For example: SELECT Data FROM Table WHERE UserID = {0}